# How can I read a message based on ftl:template java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, freemarker

Is there a way or library that could help me to parse message as below example:

```
"29032020134901ECCINOU   "
```

I want to parse it based on this ftl:template =>

```
${customerInfoMessageRequest.messageDate?right_pad(8,'0')}${customerInfoMessageRequest.messageTime?right_pad(6,'0')}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What do you mean by parsing? What is the out put you're looking for for `"29032020134901ECCINOU   "` ?

Comment: @Cortex now I have a template, like the above in question, and when I recieved a message like the message in question, I should parse it to extract Date which is first 8 digits, then extract time which is next 6 digits, now I want to write a code that parse this message based on custom template!

Comment: Again, what outcome do you want after "parsing"? You need an actual date and time object that can be formatted for example like 2020-MAR-29, 13:49:01 (and in that case, in what time zone that date-time is in)? Or you just need to extract "29032020" and "134901" as strings?

Comment: @ddekany yes sir, I need to exract them just as strings, the idea is that I need to write a code, that takes the template, and message as parameters, then extract the info. Note: I don't have any predefined tamplates!

Comment: @Abd26s Ah, you want to do it in the reverse direction... from template output, back to variables. Sorry, that doesn't work. FreeMarker templates are one way (for one, because they have `#if`-s and `#list`, etc... those are not reversible in general.).